# While compiling TrueCrypt, I get "undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'"

Tags: 13.04, compiling, truecrypt

I'm trying to compile TrueCrypt 7.1a from source on Ubuntu 13.04.
However `make` fails during the linking process with the following error:

```
Linking truecrypt
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/truecrypt-7.1a-source/tc2/Volume/Volume.a(SecurityToken.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5' is defined in DSO /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [truecrypt] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 18):

Set the environment variable `LIBS` to `-ldl`:

```
LIBS=-ldl make
```

Comment: I have `ubuntu 14.04`. Got similar error

`/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/lmdemo.dir/lmdemo.c.o: undefined reference to symbol 'exp@@GLIBC_2.2.5'`

`//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line`
You solution didn't help me. What shall I do?

Comment: Thank you!  2 hours for me to finally find this.  I was having this issue on the Raspbian Raspberry PI platform.