# Building TrueCrypt on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: security, compiling, source-code, truecrypt, open-source

With the whole NSA thing people tried to re-build identically looking binaries to the ones which truecrypt.org provides, but didn't succeed. So some think they might be compiled with back-doors which are not in the source code. -> So how compile on the latest Ubuntu version (I'm using UbuntuGNOME but that shouldn't matter)? I tried some tutorials for previous Ubuntu versions but they seem not to work any-more?

**edit:**

https://madiba.encs.concordia.ca/~x_decarn/truecrypt-binaries-analysis/ 
Now you might think "ok, we don't need to build", but: To build he used closed-source software and there are proof-of-concepts where a compromised compiler still put backdoors into the binary:
1. source without backdoors
2. binary identically to the reference-binary
3. binary contains still backdoors

**edit2 (reply to post):**

When using `$ make -j 2 PKCS11_INC=$HOME/src/pkcs-11` I get:

```
...

/usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/dynarray.h:669:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘_WX_DEFINE_TYPEARRAY_PTR’
     _WX_DEFINE_TYPEARRAY_PTR(_wxArray##name, name, base, classdecl)
     ^
/usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/dynarray.h:655:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘WX_DEFINE_TYPEARRAY_WITH_DECL_PTR’
     WX_DEFINE_TYPEARRAY_WITH_DECL_PTR(T, name, base, class WXDLLEXPORT)
     ^
/usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/dynarray.h:829:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘WX_DEFINE_EXPORTED_TYPEARRAY_PTR’
     WX_DEFINE_EXPORTED_TYPEARRAY_PTR(T, name, wxBaseArrayPtrVoid)
     ^
/usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/bookctrl.h:26:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘WX_DEFINE_EXPORTED_ARRAY_PTR’
 WX_DEFINE_EXPORTED_ARRAY_PTR(wxWindow *, wxArrayPages);
 ^
Linking truecrypt
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/src/truecrypt-7.1a-source/Volume/Volume.a(SecurityToken.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlopen@@GLIBC_2.1'
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [truecrypt] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
user@user-pc:~/src/truecrypt-7.1a-source$
```

when using `$ make -j 2 PKCS11_INC=$HOME/src/pkcs-11 LIBS=-ldl`:

```
...

Forms/VolumeSizeWizardPage.o: In function `TrueCrypt::VolumeSizeWizardPage::GetVolumeSize() const':
VolumeSizeWizardPage.cpp:(.text._ZNK9TrueCrypt20VolumeSizeWizardPage13GetVolumeSizeEv+0x80): undefined reference to `TrueCrypt::StringConverter::ToUInt64(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
Forms/VolumeSizeWizardPage.o: In function `TrueCrypt::VolumeSizeWizardPage::SetVolumeSize(unsigned long long)':
VolumeSizeWizardPage.cpp:(.text._ZN9TrueCrypt20VolumeSizeWizardPage13SetVolumeSizeEy+0x8f): undefined reference to `TrueCrypt::StringConverter::FromNumber(unsigned long long)'
Forms/WizardFrame.o: In function `TrueCrypt::WizardFrame::SetStep(int, bool)':
WizardFrame.cpp:(.text._ZN9TrueCrypt11WizardFrame7SetStepEib+0xe6): undefined reference to `TrueCrypt::Event::Connect(TrueCrypt::EventConnectorBase const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [truecrypt] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
user@user-pc:~/src/truecrypt-7.1a-source$
```

(same without the `make -j ...` parameter BTW)

**edit3**

Now it works, thanks user76204 and GEO:

1. `$ sudo apt-get install build-essential nasm libfuse-dev wx-common wx2.8-headers libwxbase2.8-dev libwxsvg-dev libwxgtk2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-dev`
2. `$ mkdir -p $HOME/src/pkcs-11`
3. put truecrypt sources to `/home/USERNAME/truecrypt-7.1a-source`
4. start building: `$ LIBS=-ldl make -j 2 PKCS11_INC=/home/USERNAME/src/pkcs-11/`

Comment: No reply? I thought people were interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
LIBS=-ldl make PKCS11_INC=/tmp/truecrypt/pkcs11
```

solved my problem (/tmp/truecrypt/pkcs11 is where my pkcs11 files are stored.)

One notice for people compiling on 14.04: do not install libwxgtk3.0-dev, use the older libwxgtk2.8-dev instead, otherwise it wont compile due to a bug in libwxgtk3.0-dev.

see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wx-users/2D_my-umcLU

Answer (score 2):

There is a [plan to audit truecrypt](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/the-truecrypt-audit) regarding the security of the software and a review of the wording of its license, which you may find interesting.

Here's how I successfully compiled it on 12.04, but it should work for later versions of Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential nasm libfuse-dev wx-common wx2.8-headers libwxbase2.8-dev libwxsvg-dev libwxgtk2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-dev
```

You also need some particular PKCS-11 header files from the official RSA site. You can get them all at once with wget, which can use `*` with ftp downloads:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/src/pkcs-11
wget 'ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-11/v2-20/pkcs11*' -P $HOME/src/pkcs-11
```

Now download the source code from [the truecrypt site](http://www.truecrypt.org/downloads2) and verify it with `gpg` after getting the public key, if necessary. Then perhaps extract it to your `~/src`.

You need to supply the name of that pkcs-11 folder containing the header files when running `make`, so give the correct path if it is different to below. Of course, replace `Truecrypt_source` with your own real path in the cd command and in the cp command below. (The Truecrypt binary will be found in the `Main` folder of the source folder.)

```
cd Truecrypt_source
make PKCS11_INC=$HOME/src/pkcs-11
sudo cp Truecrypt_source/Main/truecrypt /usr/local/bin
```

Occasionally you might have to add to the make command-line `LIBS=-ldl` as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334884/while-compiling-truecrypt-i-get-undefined-reference-to-symbol-dlcloseglibc).

Now your newly compiled truecrypt will be ready to use and you can be confident it has no backdoors.

**NOTE:** Before installing the new version, you should uninstall `truecrypt` if it is already installed with the provided uninstall script that was installed with the binary:

```
sudo /usr/bin/truecrypt-uninstall.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work, please see my edited first post for answer.

Comment: @linuxubuntu It did work on 12.04, but I'll have a look at the errors you are getting on 13.10. It could be that you have a different version of `gcc` to me, and so you could try it with `gcc 4.6.3`, as you can have different versions of `gcc` installed and select the one you wish to compile with.

Comment: Thanks. Try 13.10 in a virtual machine if you don't want to install it natively. It must be possible to compile it using v4.8. Downgrading is not a proper solution.