# Trying to compile from source newest apache with newest openssl - undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

Tags: apache2, compiling, openssl

I need to install apache 2.4.10 using openssl 1.0.1i.  I compiled openssl from source with:

```
$ ./config \
    --prefix=/opt/openssl-1.0.1i \
    --openssldir=/opt/openssl-1.0.1i
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

and Apache with:

```
./configure --prefix=/etc/apache2 \
     --enable-access_compat=shared \
     --enable-actions=shared \
     --enable-alias=shared \
     --enable-allowmethods=shared \
     --enable-auth_basic=shared \
     --enable-authn_core=shared \
     --enable-authn_file=shared \
     --enable-authz_core=shared \
     --enable-authz_groupfile=shared \
     --enable-authz_host=shared \
     --enable-authz_user=shared \
     --enable-autoindex=shared \
     --enable-dir=shared \
     --enable-env=shared \
     --enable-headers=shared \
     --enable-include=shared \
     --enable-log_config=shared \
     --enable-mime=shared \
     --enable-negotiation=shared \
     --enable-proxy=shared \
     --enable-proxy_http=shared \
     --enable-rewrite=shared \
     --enable-setenvif=shared \
     --enable-ssl=shared \
     --enable-unixd=shared \
     --enable-ssl \
     --with-ssl=/opt/openssl-1.0.1i \
     --enable-ssl-staticlib-deps \
     --enable-mods-static=ssl 
make 
(would run sudo make install next but I get an error)
```

I'm essentially following [the guide here](http://blog.ivanristic.com/2013/08/compiling-apache-with-static-openssl.html) except with newer slightly newer versions. My problem is I get a linker error when I run make for apache:

```
Making all in support
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/developer/downloads/httpd-2.4.10/support'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/developer/downloads/httpd-2.4.10/support'
/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool --silent --mode=link x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -std=gnu99  -pthread   -L/opt/openssl-1.0.1i/lib -lssl -lcrypto  \
                 -o ab  ab.lo        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaprutil-1.la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapr-1.la -lm
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/openssl-1.0.1i/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
```

I tried [the answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334884/while-compiling-truecrypt-i-get-undefined-reference-to-symbol-dlcloseglibc), but no luck. I would prefer to just use aptitude, but unfortunately the versions I need aren't available yet.  If anyone knows how to fix the linker problem (or what I think is a linker problem), or knows of a better way to tell apache to use a newer openssl, it would be greatly appreciated; I've got apache 1.0.1i working otherwise.

Comment: why dont use `sudo apt-get install openssl apache2` to install them?

Comment: "I would prefer to just use aptitude, but unfortunately the versions I need aren't available yet. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, though I'm not sure exactly what the problem was.  I changed two things:

First, I installed to a lonely directory (`--prefix=/opt/httpd/`) next to openssl.  I don't think this made a difference, but don't have time to confirm that.

Second, I compiled it with apr and apr-util source code (before I was letting it use copies I got from aptitude--the dev versions). I added apr and apr-util source code to the source tree, and used the `--with-included-apr` option when I ran apache's `./configure`.

Steps to add source code to source tree:

```
$ tar zxvf httpd-2.4.10.tar.gz
$ cd httpd-2.4.10/srclib/
$ tar zxvf ../../apr-1.5.1.tar.gz
$ ln -s apr-1.5.1/ apr
$ tar zxvf ../../apr-util-1.5.3.tar.gz
$ ln -s apr-util-1.5.3/ apr-util
```

Command used to configure apache (with other enabled modules omitted for brevity):

```
$ ./configure \
    --prefix=/opt/httpd \
    --with-included-apr \
    --enable-ssl \
    --with-ssl=/opt/openssl-1.0.1i \
    --enable-ssl-staticlib-deps \
    --enable-mods-static=ssl
```

Comment: Thanks for following up on this